# How to block spoofed local domain email sender addresses on a postfix 3.1.0 smtp relay server

Tags: networking, server, email, postfix, mail

I have `postfix 3.1.0` running as a mail gateway/filter for internal `SMTP` servers each serving their own respective domains. 
I have postscreen/spammassassin/amavisd etc running on this email gateway/filter.
This is successful in blocking 99% of spam but I find a lot of spam coming in from spoofed local domain addresses. I would like to block these prior to any virus/spam checking much like the `rbl` checks in `postscreen` work. Well at more or the less the same point in the process anyway.
Local SMTP sender authentication is disabled - this is just a relay server for internal domains. So I assume that any `smtp_sender_restrictions` in `main.cf` would be useless in this case? 
Do I need to set up a table and refer to it in the " `smtpd_relay_restrictions`" within `main.cf` ? Not sure how to tackle this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out and implemented this solution:
In '/etc/postfix' I created a file 'domain_blacklist'
and added the following text to it:
    'mylocal-domain.com 550 service unavailable'

in 'main.cf' under 'smtpd_recipient_restrictions' added 'check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/domain_blacklist' just before 'reject_unknown_recipient_domain'

run 'postmap domain_blacklist'
and reloaded postfix - works just fine now